# Rest Assured response body validation

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a question related to response body validation in Rest Assured. Let's suppose, I have such a response body as json.

```
{
    "store": {
        "books_count":3,
        "books": [
            {
                "genre": "fiction",
                "author": {
                    "name": "William",
                    "lastName" : "Evans"
                }
            },
            {
                "genre": "kids",
                "author": {
                    "name": "Eric",
                    "lastName" : "Carle"
                }
            },
            {
                "genre": "science",
                "author": {
                    "name": "Ronald",
                    "lastName" : "Forks"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to check:

1. if books section contains a kids genre
2. if a book of kids genre has autor name as Eric

the first assertion can be like:

```
response.body("store.books.genre", hasItem("kids);
```

But then I need to check if its author's name is William. Is there any way to check it using jsonPath?

I assume, that I can do deserialization (e.x. List<Book.class>, and then get an Author.class etc...), but is there any opportunity to check it with RestAssured. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if a book of kids genre has autor name as Eric

You can leverage the GPath to extract value by condition

```
.body("store.books.find {it.genre == 'kids'}.author.name", is("Eric");
```

Answer (score 0):

Used jayway json path library

// Read your response
Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/myJson.json"));

// convert byte stream into string

```
    String responseData =
            new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/test/resources/myJson.json")));
```

1. first part

   ```
   List<String> genreList = JsonPath.parse(responseData).read("$..genre");
   System.out.println(genreList.contains("kids"));// we can use assertions as well
   ```
2. Second part

   ```
   List<Map<String, Object>> getAuthor = JsonPath.parse(responseData).read("$..[?( @['genre']=='kids')]");
   Map<String, Object> title = (Map<String, Object>) getAuthor.get(0).get("author");
   String author = (String) title.get("name");
   System.out.println(author);
   // assertEquals("Eric", author);
   ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).